# How to make methods flow like glide library?

Tags: java, android

Glide.with(context)
        .load(param)
        .apply(param)
        .into(param);

Comment: What do you want to do with glide

Comment: the issue is not with glide i wanna to made a class like glide with the same style of methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a design pattern called Builder.

[Builder design pattern , sourcemaking.com](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder)

Its about returning `this`

```
class UserObjectBuilder {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

    UserObjectBuilder withId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    UserObjectBuilder withName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    UserObjectBuilder withEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
        return this;
    }

    User build() {
        return new User(id, name, email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer ?

Comment: The idea is that the builder object's functions keep returning itself. Any method in the builder object does something, and returns itself, so you can directly execute another method on this returned value which is the same object.

Comment: `new UserBuilderObject()` is of type `UserBuilderObject`. `new UserBuilderObject().withId(1)` sends `1` to the function, and returns the same object, which is also of type `UserBuilderObject`, so you can also execute other methods. `new UserBuilderObject().withId(1).withName("name")` does also return the same object, which is with type `UserBuilderObject`.

Comment: This answer is pretty much correct. The only difference is that Glide uses a static method to create instances rather than using a constructor.

Comment: Easy,    also in `UserBuilderObject` example, `build` couldn't be called if you don't call `new UserBuilderObject()`.   You can change the `UserBuilderObject` to contain a static public factory method `public static UserBuilderObject createObject() { return UserBuilderObject(); }`, then when you want to call you could `UserBuilderObject.createObject().withId(1).withName("name").build()`

Comment: thank for answer it was really helpful and its worked with me